# how to get the selected option id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select

I'm looking for some way to print the ID, or let me select the ID from an option in a select

here my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#direcciones-envio-usuario").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker show-tick" id="direcciones-envio-usuario" data-width="85%" data-header="Eligir dirección">
  <option>Mi casa</option>
  <option>Casa de pepe</option>
  <option data-divider="true"></option>
  <option data-icon="glyphicon-plus-sign" id="nueva_direccion_btn">Nueva dirección</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Most of your options don't have an ID, what should it show for them? Why don't you use `this.value` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared this example in a fiddle, i hope will be useful https://jsfiddle.net/jgonzalez315/8znq29g7/

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#direcciones-envio-usuario").change(function(){
         alert($( "#direcciones-envio-usuario option:selected" ).text()); 
          if($( "#direcciones-envio-usuario option:selected" ).text()=="Nueva dirección")
      {
        //IF YOU WANT attr id
        alert($( "#direcciones-envio-usuario option:selected" ).attr('id'));
       }

    });
 })
```

Comment: I'm trying to make is that when I select the option "Nueva dirección" that has "nueva_direccion_btn" ID class want to add and remove other div class

Comment: Well you should set in the "if" that identify the option selected something like this  $( "selector" ).removeClass( "myClass noClass" ).addClass( "yourClass" );

Comment: i updated the fiddle, and you can see you dont need exactly remove or add class to hide and show divs https://jsfiddle.net/jgonzalez315/8znq29g7/1/

Answer (score 3):

Use `change` event instead of click `event`, here use `:selected` selector

```
$("#direcciones-envio-usuario").change(function(){
     alert($(':selected', this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oPkYvWKlMCAUK7u60RBy)

The main code to get this to work for your example is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#direcciones-envio-usuario").change(function(){
    alert($(this).children("option:selected").attr("id"));
  });
})
```

I think this solves what you were tring to achieve. Let me know if you need any refinements :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$("#direcciones-envio-usuario").change(function(){
    alert($(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));
});
```

Also, since it is a `select` element it would be wise to change your event to `.change()` instead of `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contextual `this` to select the child, which is selected, and get its `ID` attribute.

```
$("#direcciones-envio-usuario").change(function(){
     alert($(this).find(":selected").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: @1999, Added info buddy!